# GLSL define does calculation or replaces text?

Tags: glsl, webgl, c-preprocessor

For something relatively expensive but constant such as `pow()` with pre-runtime user specified constants, can a `define` be used to reduce the runtime calculation? Or would each appearance of `define` just be replaced with what it defines?

For example, is there any benefit to this:

```
#define MENGER_ITER 3
#define MENGER_ITER_POW pow(3.0, -float(MENGER_ITER))

// ...other code
return (length(max(abs(vec3(x, y, z))-1.0, 0.0))-0.25)*MENGER_ITER_POW;
// ...other code
```

As opposed to this:

```
// ...other code
return (length(max(abs(vec3(x, y, z))-1.0, 0.0))-0.25)*pow(3.0, -float(MENGER_ITER));
// ...other code
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#define` just does a text substitution

For your case it's no different than

```
shaderSource = shaderSource.replace(/MENGER_ITER_POW/g, "pow(3.0, -float(MENGER_ITER))");
shaderSource = shaderSource.replace(/MENGER_ITER/g, "3");
gl.shaderSource(someShader, shaderSource);
```

It's very similar to [the C/C++ preprocessor](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/)

The benefit is it makes your code more readable?

Comment: Thanks, that value is calculated very often in one of my shaders for a fractal. The exact number of times is unknown (depends on the scene and angle of the camera) but it could be more than 50,000 times (per pixel). I should just store it in a global float instead then?

Comment: I don't know. Theoretically the GLSL compiler should see it's all constants and optimize it into a single value at compile time but I can imagine some drivers don't do that. You could test both ways, one with a value you pre-calculate and other with your macros as is and see if you notice a difference in perf. Unfortunately it could be different on every GPU/Driver :(  To be clear, you could do this in JS. `var MENGER_ITER =3; src = src.replace(/MENGER_ITER_POW/g, Math.pow(3.0, -MENGER_ITER));`